Shower door sweep for an unframed glass door hitting frame
I’m a DIY novice — so please forgive any informal speak here:
Just moved into a house and noticed the shower door doesn’t have a sweep to help keep the water in.
The door is glass without a frame, but makes contact with a frame bottom.
Here’s pictures of the door from the outside and inside shower


It looks like there’s plenty of space for a sweep of some kind…
Majority of sweeps I’ve looked up are for frameless set ups. If I understand that correctly, that means the shower door doesn’t make contact with a frame.
Others are framed set ups but involve the door also having a frame, which mine does not.
I can see the manufacturer is Trulite, but the rest of the etching is unreadable, so I’m having trouble looking up details.
Do I need a sweep, and if so, which one do I get?!

Trulite is the manufacturer of the glass panel that is used as a door. A bath specialty store or a glass shop that supplies custom showers should be able to guide you.

Some options: https://www.swisco.com/1-4-sweep-drip-98/pd/Lavatory-Replacement-Hardware/10-335 https://www.swisco.com/Frameless-Shower-Seal/pd/Lavatory-Replacement-Hardware/10-329
